# Print out four lines side by side, then start over

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I have a file

```
6/28
Save As You Go Transfer Credit From Xxxxxxxxxxx3495
1.00
10.00
7/7
Save As You Go Transfer Credit From Xxxxxxxxxxx3495
1.00
11.00
7/8
Save As You Go Transfer Credit From Xxxxxxxxxxx3495
1.00
12.00
7/12
Save As You Go Transfer Credit From Xxxxxxxxxxx3495
1.00
13.00
```

I want to print it like `$line $line $line $line`, then every four lines, then start a new line. I figured that a loop was the way to go - but it is not working

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
for ((i=0; i<3 ; i++;))
do
echo $line | tr "\n" " "

done
i=0
done < /tmp/moo.txt
```

This is how I want the file printed out:

```
6/28 Save As You Go Transfer Credit From Xxxxxxxxxxx3495 1.00 10.00
7/7 Save As You Go Transfer Credit From Xxxxxxxxxxx3495 1.00 11.00
7/8 Save As You Go Transfer Credit From Xxxxxxxxxxx3495 1.00 12.00
7/12 Save As You Go Transfer Credit From Xxxxxxxxxxx3495 1.00 13.00
```

~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `N` [mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `4` changes in range `[0;3]` periodically: `1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, ...`, you can test if the result of the modulo operation is zero, and print a newline character if it is:

```
i=0
while read line
do
  printf '%s ' "$line"
  (( ++i % 4 )) || printf '\n'
done < /tmp/moo.txt
```

In this example, `printf` prints the next line from the file with an appended space( `%s`). The `%s` format specification stands for a string (the first argument is a format string, the next arguments are passed according to the format string).

The expression `(( ++i % 4 ))` is an [arithmetic expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) that increments the `i` variable by one, then performs the modulo 4 operation. Note the use of *pre-increment* operator.

In arithmetic context, zero is interpreted as boolean [*false*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_%28logic%29). The `printf '\n'` command is executed, if the result of the arithmetic operation is zero due to the OR [operator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html) `||`. Some examples for clarity:

```
(( 0 )) || echo zero
(( 1 )) && echo non-zero || echo zero
```

*Output*

```
zero
non-zero
```

It is easy to fix the trailing space (just before the newline) by adding some extra logic:

```
i=0
while read line
do
  (( ++i % 4 )) && d=' ' || d=$'\n'
  printf '%s%s' "$line" "$d"
done < /tmp/moo.txt
```

Note the use of [ANSI C-quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) for the newline character: `$'\n'`.

**The Same Using AWK**

The same logic may be implemented using the AWK utility:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", $0, (NR % 4 ? " " : "\n") }' /tmp/moo.txt
```

where we have used [AWK's conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Conditional-Exp), and the [built-in auto-set](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset) `NR` variable.

**P.S.**

Why `printf`? [There are serious reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: what is the print '%s '

Comment: what does this say (in vernacular)  (( ++i % 4 )) || printf '\n'

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
for ((i=0; i<3 ; i++;))
do
echo -n `echo $line | tr "\n" " "`

done
i=0
done < /tmp/moo.txt
```